# Selection equality in condition in altair plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair, vega-lite

I would like to make an interactive plot using Altair, that can be formulated in a simple example: Suppose I have four houses A, B, C, D located geographically in a 2x2 grid. For each pair of houses, there is an associated friendship-score to indicate the mutual friendship. A nice visualization of this would be to plot the 2x2 grid of the houses, and when I click on one of the tiles the friendship score is indicated on all the other tiles with a colour coding.

I have a solution that only works when clicking on one of the tiles. The three other tiles are unaffected when selecting them. In the example below, I also plot the friendship-score matrix below (for clarity), and here the colouring based on the selection does seem to work.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

families = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

# geographical house locations
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [1, 2, 1, 2],
        "y": [1, 1, 2, 2],
        "house1": families,
    }
)

# friendship data
firendship_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3], [2, 2, 0, 1], [3, 3, 1, 0]], columns=families
)
firendship_df = firendship_df.set_index(firendship_df.columns)

# convert friendship matrix to long format
friendship_df_lf = (
    firendship_df.melt(var_name="house1", value_name="friendship", ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "house2"})
)

df = pd.merge(df, friendship_df_lf, how="left", on="house1")


selector = alt.selection_single(name="SelectorName", fields=["house1"])

base = (
    alt.Chart(df, width=200, height=200)
    .mark_rect(strokeWidth=1, stroke="white")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("x:N"),
        y=alt.Y("y:N"),
    )
)

geo_chart = (
    base.mark_rect(strokeWidth=1, stroke="white")
    .add_selection(selector)
    .transform_calculate(selected_val=selector["house1"])
    .encode(
        color=alt.condition(
            "datum.selected_val==datum.house2",
            alt.Color(
                "friendship:O",
                scale=alt.Scale(scheme="redyellowblue", domain=[0, 1, 2, 3]),
            ),
            alt.value("grey"),
        ),
    )
)


score_chart = (
    alt.Chart(friendship_df_lf, width=200, height=200)
    .mark_rect()
    .encode(
        x="house1:N",
        y="house2:N",
        color=alt.condition(
            selector,
            alt.Color(
                "friendship:O",
                scale=alt.Scale(scheme="redyellowblue", domain=[0, 1, 2, 3]),
            ),
            alt.value("grey"),
        ),
    )
)

# add house labels to plot
text_chart = base.mark_text().encode(text="house1")
tot_chart = geo_chart + text_chart

alt.vconcat(tot_chart, score_chart).show()
```

Plot that works as intented when clicking house D:

[Plot that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCxfw.png)

Plot that shows the problem when clicking other houses. Here house A:

[Plot with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3dPp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the clicked tile in the `geo_chart` and the corresponding column in the `score_chart` to be highlight when you click in the `geo_chart`. To achieve this, you can change the color condition for the `geo_chart` from `"datum.selected_val==datum.house2"` to just `selector` as for the other chart.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I want. On the `geo_chart` I would like to click on a tile (e.g. tile (1,1)) and the then all the rest of the tiles are coloured according to the mutual friendship score (e.g. friendship score between (1,1)-(1,2), (1,1)-(2,2) and (1,1)-(2,1))